# C++ compile error (Your class or method was improperly declared)

Tags: c++

I m trying to submit Solution written in C++ for a Topcoder Problem.

The code is running my local machine (Ubuntu 12.04 Linux, gcc)

But I get the following error while compiling (Topcoder Compiler).

errors compiling:

```
In file included from top level:11:
Your class or method was improperly declared: In function ‘std::string _wrapper::thunk(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::string)’:
Your class or method was improperly declared:20003: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct UserName’
end of your submission:10030: error: forward declaration of ‘struct UserName’
```

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class Username {

    public:
        string newMember(vector <string> existingNames, string newName) {
            int i, j, result = 0;
            for(i=0;i<existingNames.size();i++) {
                if(newName == existingNames[i]) {
                    result = 1;
                }
            }
            if(result == 1) {
                for(i=1;i<50;i++) {
                    result = 0;
                    string newUsername = newName;
                    stringstream k;
                    k << i;
                    newUsername += k.str();
                    for(j=0; j<existingNames.size(); j++) {
                        if(newUsername == existingNames[j]) {
                            result = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if (result == 0) {
                        return(newUsername);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return(newName);
            }
        }
};
```

Can someone please, point me to where I m actually going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that is your code? Your code has a class `Username`, but the compilation error is about a struct `UserName`.

Comment: Yep! I double checked it.

Comment: The code is running fine on my machine. I tried submitting the solution by copy pasting it there.

Comment: There's something else at play here, post more info. Compiler could be upset about something const that isn't declared const? that template error looks like it failed to match a type. The error could be caused by something you do with _wrapper happening before it knows about this class

Comment: Is the question perhaps asking for you to create a `UserName` class, which you haven't done, but which other code is looking for?

Comment: Following is the link to the Topcoder Problem http://pastebin.com/aR8PJdG6! The Definition says to create a Class Username and method newMember. Thats exactly what I ve done in my code.

Comment: Well, that answers that. You're indeed supposed to be creating a `UserName` class, not a `Username` class. "Class: UserName / Method: newMember" :)